# Rider uses mono32 to execute unit tests instead of mono64 macOS

Tags: .net, mono, macos-catalina, rider

I need to run unit test made in .NET Framework version 4.5. I am running this system:

- **OS**: `macOS Catalina`
- **Version**: `10.15.5`

Because I have a macOS system I installed Mono on the official website. The version I installed is: `6.10.0.104`. It supports mono32 as well as mono64, but for some odd reason my IDE (Rider) is using mono32 to run tests. I am just wondering how I can force mono64 to be used?

The error that is thrown is:

```
Exit code is 1 (Error: --arch=32 Failed to switch to '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono32'.
```

The version of Rider that I use is: `JetBrains Rider 2020.1.3 Build #RD-201.7846.1`.

I have found a similar question [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000670090-How-to-run-with-64-bit-mono-), but no one answered that question unfortunately.

Thank you for helping me in advance!

Comment: What unit testing framework did you use? How did you configure it? If your project was forced to run as 32 bit, you need to revise the settings to run as 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed "Default platform architecture" to "x64" in Preferences > Unit Testing and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I forgot to answer this question myself as this indeed fixed my issue eventually. I accepted your answer since it is the right one. Thanks!

Comment: This was set to `automatic` for me, which clearly wasn't working. Explicitly setting `x64` sorted it. Thanks!